# -bash: export: `PATH;': not a valid identifier

Tags: macos, visual-studio, terminal

When I open terminal on my Mac, I get this error message after installing Visual Studio for Mac.

```
  -bash: export: `PATH;': not a valid identifier
```

Now my grunt commands, etc do not work. Did VS break something?

Comment: Did you mean to ask "What could be the reason for this, and how can I fix it?", because the answer to your question is "apparently, yes". Also, this might be better suited for [su].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your [Bash Profile](https://natelandau.com/my-mac-osx-bash_profile/) file, in `/Users/USERNAME/.bash_profile`, and look for lines starting with:

```
export PATH=...
```

or

```
PATH=...
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like something was set for EDITOR variable pointing to my Textmate text editor, I removed that it and it fixed the issue.